# Post Request gives a 405 error in Postman

Tags: json, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, postman, asp.net-core-webapi

on my .Net Web Api, I have an entity model, request model and response model for each database table. When i make a post request to MedTestOrder, i receive a 405 error, but other entities are working fine. I will post code snippets of MedTestOrder entity model, request model, response model, controller and service. The models contain foreign keys and I suspect my error could be from there. I might be wrong or not. I just need help.

1 - Entity Model

```
namespace Africanbiomedtests.Entities
{
        public class MedTestOrder
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int? MedTestId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("MedTestId")]
        public MedTest MedTest { get; set; }
        public int? healthcareProviderId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("healthcareProviderId")]
        public HealthcareProvider healthcareProvider { get; set; }
        public int? accountId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("accountId")]
        public Account Account { get; set; }
        public int? newbornId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("newbornId")]
        public Newborn Newborn { get; set; }
        public string PaymentStatus { get; set; }
        public Boolean CompletionStatus { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateCompleted { get; set; }
        public DateTime? Updated { get; set; }

    }

}
```

2 - Api Request Model

```
namespace Africanbiomedtests.Models.MedTestsOrder
{
    public class MedTestsOrderCreateRequest
    {
        [Required]
        public MedTest MedTest { get; set; }

        public HealthcareProvider healthcareProvider { get; set; }

        public Account Account { get; set; }

        public Newborn Newborn { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string PaymentStatus { get; set; }
        public Boolean CompletionStatus { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }

    }
}
```

3 - Response Model

```
namespace Africanbiomedtests.Models.MedTestsOrder
{
    public class MedTestsOrderResponse
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public MedTest MedTest { get; set; }
        public HealthcareProvider healthcareProvider { get; set; }
        public Account Account { get; set; }
        public Newborn Newborn { get; set; }
        public string PaymentStatus { get; set; }
        public Boolean CompletionStatus { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateCompleted { get; set; }

    }
}
```

4 - Controller

```
[Authorize]
[HttpPost("create")]
public ActionResult<MedTestsOrderResponse> Create(MedTestsOrderCreateRequest model)
{
    var medTestOrder = _medTestOrderService.Create(model);
    return Ok(medTestOrder);
}
```

5 - Service

```
public MedTestsOrderResponse Create(MedTestsOrderCreateRequest model)
        {

            // map model to new account object
            var medTestOrder = _mapper.Map<MedTestOrder>(model);
            medTestOrder.DateCreated = DateTime.UtcNow;


            // save account
            _context.MedTestOrder.Add(medTestOrder);
            _context.SaveChanges();

            return _mapper.Map<MedTestsOrderResponse>(medTestOrder);
        }
```

6 - Postman JSON request

```
{
    "medTestId": 3,
    "healthcareProviderId": 3,
    "accountId": 1004,
    "newbornId": 1,
    "paymentStatus": "Complete Payment",
    "completionStatus": "1",
    "dateCompleted": "01/14/2021"
}
```

I would really appreciate any help right now

Comment: Make sure in postman you are using a `POST` and not a `GET` method. 405 is `method not allowed`.

When hitting an endpoint that is found, you get a 405 when not using the right http method.

I would also suggest using `[Route("create")]` as an additional attribute, and not `[HttpPost("create")]`

Can you add your entire CURL from postman?

Comment: @Caleb Igwe, 405 indicates the http verbs is different. From the request body in postman, it should encounter a 400 error. Because the referenced entity should be in the form of map. If it is still not solved, can you share some captures?

Comment: @Marius CURL from postman? I am just hearing of that for the first time. How do i go about that?

Answer (score 3):

Thank you @Marius and @Karney, I realized i wasn't using the correct endpoint. I needed to add "/create" to my endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

In some cases, your Web API method accepts only PUT requests, Try to put not post.